# PostgreSQL query involving integer[]

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE article (  
  id serial NOT NULL,
  title text,
  tags integer[] -- array of tag id's from TAG table
)

CREATE TABLE tag (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  description character varying(250) NOT NULL
)
```

... and need to select tags from TAG table held in ARTICLE's 'tags integer[]'  based on article's title.

So tried something like

```
SELECT *  
  FROM tag 
 WHERE tag.id IN ( (select article.tags::int4 
                      from article 
                     where article.title = 'some title' ) );
```

... which gives me

> ERROR:  cannot cast type integer[] to integer
>   LINE 1: ...FROM tag WHERE tag.id IN (  (select article.tags::int4 from ...

I am Stuck with PostgreSql 8.3 in both dev and production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the array overlaps operator `&&`:

```
SELECT *
    FROM tag
    WHERE ARRAY[id] && ANY (SELECT tags FROM article WHERE title = '...');
```

Using `contrib/intarray` you can even index this sort of thing quite well.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at section "[8.14.5. Searching in Arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING)", but consider the tip at the end of that section:

> **Tip**: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

Answer (score 2):

You did not mention your Postgres version, so I assume you are using an up-to-date version (8.4, 9.0)

This should work then:

```
SELECT *  
  FROM tag 
 WHERE tag.id IN ( select unnest(tags)
                     from article 
                    where title = 'some title' );
```

But you should really consider changing your table design.

**Edit**

For 8.3 the unnest() function can easily be added, see this wiki page:
http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Unnest

Comment: ... bummer, I'm 8.3, both dev and prod :-(

Comment: ... you bet me to it, that's what I found :-)